# Extracting largest values from certain columns in Bash

Tags: bash

Please tell me how to write a bash script that finds the following:

1. the lines containing the 5 largest values from column 1
2. the line containing the second largest value from column 1
3. the line number of the lines containing the 5 largest values from column 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort` with `head` and `tail`:

```
# the lines containing the 5 largest values from column 1
sort -n somefile.csv --reverse | head -n 5
# the line containing the second largest value from column 1
sort -n somefile.csv --reverse | head -n 2 | tail -n 1
```

For the last part you need the line numbers as well, so add them using `cat --number` and use the same method:

```
cat --number somefile.csv | sort -nk2 --reverse | head -n 5
```

Note that column 2 is used as the key in the last command since the first column contains the line numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!